# calculate time difference like facebook messaging system

Tags: php, facebook-like

I need to find time difference for `like` in facebook messages using php.

```
like: 2 weeks ago, 2 hr 30 mins ago, one second ago
```

My time format is "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Can Anyone help me with it?

Comment: i can find it with dayz only not with hour minute and seconds.

Answer (score 14):

Store the message created time in database then use below function :

```
function get_time_difference_php($created_time)
 {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); //Change as per your default time
        $str = strtotime($created_time);
        $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        // It returns the time difference in Seconds...
        $time_differnce = $today-$str;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Years...
        $years = 60*60*24*365;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Months...
        $months = 60*60*24*30;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Days...
        $days = 60*60*24;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Hours...
        $hours = 60*60;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Minutes...
        $minutes = 60;

        if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 1)
        {
            return intval($time_differnce/$years)." years ago";
        }else if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 0)
        {
            return intval($time_differnce/$years)." year ago";
        }else if(intval($time_differnce/$months) > 1)
        {
            return intval($time_differnce/$months)." months ago";
        }else if(intval(($time_differnce/$months)) > 0)
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$months))." month ago";
        }else if(intval(($time_differnce/$days)) > 1)
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$days))." days ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$days)) > 0) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$days))." day ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$hours)) > 1) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$hours))." hours ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$hours)) > 0) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$hours))." hour ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$minutes)) > 1) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$minutes))." minutes ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$minutes)) > 0) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce/$minutes))." minute ago";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce)) > 1) 
        {
            return intval(($time_differnce))." seconds ago";
        }else
        {
            return "few seconds ago";
        }
  }
```